# How to recover Cloudera cluster if Database of cludera is deleted?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I have accidentally deleted the cloudera server DB Data files stored in

```
/var/lib/
```

I have already given up on recovering the data from recovery software.

Please let me know if there is any way to start cloudera or if i can only install cloudera only and register hadoop components to it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much you can do. You'll have to reinstall and reconfigure your cluster. You'll probably be able to recover data that was stored on HDFS. Also, you can backup cluster configs that are stored in /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/ for later reference.

Comment: can't i reinstall cloudera and register the components of hadoop?

Comment: No. Cloudera Manager stores all config parameters of your cluster in its database (that is now gone). It generates config files on-the-fly when you start a service. So, if you are concerned about the configuration, you'll have to setup and reconfigure everything from scratch. If you are concerned about data you had in HDFS, you still have options to get it back.

Comment: Yes finally it start working after installing CDH again